# MS Access move visible selected row to last row in currently visible (active) table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to move the visible selected row on the currently-visible table to the last row of the table so that I can manually fill in the fields to create a new record. But I can't find VBA to move the Selection (selected row) to the last row in the open table. My code is shown below, but it fails to do what I want, and I can't find any explanations or examples on the net.

If I had the index of the last row in the table (.RecordCount from somewhere?) and some syntax for setting the visible cursor to that row (maybe `records(index).Selected = true` or something like that?), I could accomplish my goal. Thank you.

```
Sub TableLastRowMove()
Dim tbl As AccessObject, tblname As String
tblname = Application.CurrentObjectName

' get a handle to the currently open table and print its name
Set tbl = Application.CurrentData.AllTables(tblname)
Debug.Print tbl.name

' I want to move the visible selected record to the end of the table
' I think I need something like
'    set selection = ActiveTable.LastRow
' But that is not available in Access

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & tbl.name)
If Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveLast
    ' I want to say
    ' rs.currentRecord.Selected = true
    ' but that is not available either
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use form to interact with data? Users should not work directly with tables and queries.

Comment: Normally I agree, but there are cases where it just isn't worth it to create a form for e.g. a configuration table that a handful of users may need to edit once or twice a year. @June7

Comment: If it helps, I am in the process of developing an application but want to build the database and app functionality before I tackle the whole UI development problem. The reason for the question is that the tables are getting long enough that I'm tired of scrolling down to the "New*" record to enter data manually. I wish I had a Form, but that's a long way off. A macro to scroll for me is a lighter, faster, and easier way to solve my immediate issue. So both June7 and Andre are partially right, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```vb
strObjName = "myTable"

DoCmd.OpenTable strObjName

' Go to the new record at the bottom
DoCmd.GoToRecord acActiveDataObject, strObjName, acNewRec

' This would go to the last record    
' DoCmd.GoToRecord acActiveDataObject, strObjName, acLast
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I see now that acNewRec means go to the "new" record, not "Create a new record" (which was my interpretation before). Do you also have syntax to force the visible cursor into the first field of the record? Thank you

Comment: Isn't the cursor always in the first column after opening the table? It is for me. @Kevin

Comment: Hi Andre, it is when the table is opened, but my table is already open and my cursor is in a different column because I have been editing the cell. When I run the command above the cursor moves to the right line but stays in the old column.

Comment: Oh, I see. Not really. You can try `DoCmd.Requery` which would "reset" the table (go back to row 1, col 1) before the command. But that might be more annoying than useful. Or press TAB (to go out of edit mode) and HOME (goes to 1st column). @Kevin